# How to exclude in SQL with WHERE clause?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a WHERE clause in a large query that always exclude all records with the colour RED.

I however want to add another WHERE clause that exclude all records with the colour RED EXCEPT for when the age of the car is = 5.

Here's a some dummy data to better visualize how my data is built:

[image]

How would I integrate this into my large query to achieve this?

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
TABLE1
WHERE COLOUR NOT LIKE '%RED%';
```

How would I modify this query to exclude all RED records EXCEPT when AGE = 5?

I am working in Snowflake.

Answer (score 2):

The second condition needs to be connected using `OR`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE COLOUR NOT LIKE '%RED%'
  OR AGE = 5;
```